# How can I handle GET data in koa

Tags: get, router, koa, koa-router

I am newbie in koa, and I am using koa-router.
For me, the code is like:

```
this.router.get('/user/test',function(){
            debugger;
        })
```

then I visit localhost:3000/user/test?p=1&q=2, I just find that there seems no method for me to get the value of p and q.
So how can I quickly get the value?

Comment: Did you try `this.query`? http://koajs.com/#request-query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var route = require('koa-route');
var koa = require('koa');
var app = koa();

// /user/test/?a=1&b=2 -> will console log your values
app.use(route.get('/user/test', function* () {
  console.log(this.query.a)
  console.log(this.query.b)
}));
```